# how to make background color on selected icon of navigation bar/ bottom app bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make the selected icon on navigation bar have some background color on it, somehow it will become like this. This is my code.[image]

```
BottomNavigationBar bottom_navbar_home(){  
   return BottomNavigationBar( 
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home_filled), label: 'Home'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.feed_outlined), label: 'Activity'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet_outlined),
                    label: 'Wallet'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble_outline),
                    label: 'Notification'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: 'Settings'),
              ],

   );
}
```

Comment: Refer to this it helps you -> https://github.com/dhola-hardik/flutter_api_call_dio/blob/main/lib/src/home_page.dart

Answer (score 1):

try my code it worked for me

```
 BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
    label: '',
    tooltip: 'home',
    activeIcon: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.home,
          color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
        )),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll like this solution, but you can change the color of the selected Icon (or changing the Selected icon to another). for that, you can just use the `activeIcon` property to  change the color of the Icon you selected, like this:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon( Icons.account_balance_wallet_outlined,
                          color: Colors.black,
              ),
              label: 'Wallet', 
              activeIcon:Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet_outlined,color: Colors.black,)
          ),
```

This will look better if you change the `type` property of the `BottomNavigationBar` to: `type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting`, which is recomended when the `BottomNavigationBar` has more than three (3) items